# Python RegEx to Catch White Space Between Array Name and Size

Tags: linux, python, arrays, python-3.x

I am using a regular expression in a python script to search through a file to find variable declarations. This is what I have so far:

```
ret1 = re.compile(r'^\s*(volatile|register|typedef)?\s?([\w<>:*, ]+?)\s+([\w:]+)[\w:\[\]]*\s*;\s*$')

ret2 = ret1.match(nextLineInFile)

print("Group 2: ", ret2.group(2))#variable type
print("Group 3: ", ret2.group(3))#variable name
```

Later in the code, I'm using groupings to capture the variable type and the variable name. I have the following input:

```
long myArray1[2];
long myArray2 [2];
long long myArray3[2];
long long myArray4 [2];
```

My RegEx is only finding myArray1 and myArray3. I need it find all four declarations. I've tried the following:

```
ret = re.compile(r'^\s*(volatile|register|typedef)?\s?([\w<>:*, ]+?)\s+([\w:]+)\s*[\w:\[\]]*\s*;\s*$')
```

This catches myArray1, myArray2, and myArray4 perfectly. But, now myArray3 is coming back with a variable type of "long" and variable name of "long". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Voting to move this to Stackoverflow as it's not a Unix or Linux question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering a bit with your input and current regex, I've come to the following expression : `^\s*(volatile|register|typedef)?\s?([\w<>:*, ]+?)\s+([\w:]+)\s?\[\d+\]\s*;\s*$`.

Instead of Looking for `arrayName[size]` and `arrayName [size]` as two separate elements, i'm just looking to find the name of the array `([\w<>:*, ]+?)` followed or not by a space `\s?`, and then by the brackets with the size [\d+].

You can test the expression at https://regex101.com/r/6KDHjj/1

Do not hesitate if you have any question about my expression, or if it does not work as expected.

Another possibility I just thought of would be to have the part matching the type of the array be greedy : `^\s*(volatile|register|typedef)?\s?([\w<>:*, ]+)\s+([\w:]+)\s*[\w:\[\]]*\s*;\s*$`.
I just removed the interrogation mark at the end of `([\w<>:*, ]+?)` to get this behaviour.

Here is a test of this second possibility : https://regex101.com/r/WMWC93/1

Comment: I didn't try your first solution. But, your second solution worked perfectly! Thank you!